# Create a plugin with configure, autogen make like in gst 1.0 source. And also may be create a tool chain for raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, gstreamer, raspberry-pi2, toolchain

I am writing a gst plugin for my raspberry pi 2 from scratch.

I have basic code for my test gst plugin.
I am currently compiling gstreamer 1.0 for the raspberry pi using 
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc as compiler with armv7a and vfpv3-d16 flags.

So here is what I want to do:
I want to make this test plugin of mine have the aautogen, configure and make features that the gst 1.0 source code has.
Also I want anyone who wants to make changes to be able to download the source code for my plugin and compile it for raspberry pi.

Is it possible to place the binaries for gst 1.0 and dependencies somewhere so that the someone else who uses the source code of mine does not have to recompile gst1.0 at their end? Like a tool chain?

So how do I add these to my plugin's source code?

I am complete noob and trying to learn all about toolchains, cross compiling etc.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

- to have cross compiled libraries, preferrably at one place - gstreamer has certain hierarchy of libraries

either:

- you have *.pc files to be able to use pkg-config to get the libraries paths (maybe you have to manually edit them)

or

- set all the env variables which tells the compiler where to find includes and libraries

then

- bundle everything together, you can create a deb package for all this with dependancy on your toolchain

Also be warned that the default *.pc files are pointing to *.la instead of *.so - I usually change it manually, but I guess this is not a problem when you are creating a plugin - I dont know.

just a little idea, maybe it will help you or set you on wrong path.
The idea is to use [gst-uninstalled](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/scripts/gst-uninstalled) script which has all this solved so you dont have to think of how to edit the *.pc files or set env variables.

To initialize gst-uninstalled use [create gst-uninstalled script](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/plain/scripts/create-uninstalled-setup.sh)

You cross-compile whole gstreamer with this gst-uninstalled "environment" and bundle it into deb package with all the libs (all the time in `.libs` folder), `*.pc` files and `*.h` files (well you do not need source code - the *.c files)
// or maybe you do not have to cross-compile again, and just move the already compiled folders into your gst-uninstalled root directory

HTH

Comment: Thanks otopolsky. I am looking forward to building more of an development environment here. Something like a toolchain. I would like to use the  arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc compiler. But would like to create a dev environment for anyone to use, edit and compile the code to pi2. That's why the interest in make and auto-config